# Seeking Advice on Acquiring Clean Experimental data comprises of proteins for FDR Estimation

Tags: proteins, literature-search, mass-spectrometry, computational-biochemistry

I am a bioinformatics student doing my research on top-down mass spectrometry-based proteomics and seeking some guidance on acquiring very clean experimental data with known true positives and false positives. I want to assess my proposed FDR estimation method under controlled conditions and would appreciate your insights on obtaining high-quality experimental data.
My question is

1. Any tips on acquiring clean experimental data with known true positives?
2. Any suggestion on sample types or protocols you recommend for ensuring a reliable dataset for FDR estimation?
3. How can one introduce controlled errors or variations, like false positives, while maintaining the overall data quality? If anyone has any idea or experience or any paper suggestion in which they used a similar approach please share thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.